# CPU Usage per core in multi socket server C#

Tags: c#, server, cpu, cpu-usage, multicore

I'm going to get CPU Usage per core in a lot of computers that have multi SMPs and multi cores in each SMP. some of them are hyperthreaded.
I used this code but it takes a lot of CPU cycle and time and even not working.

```
var pc = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time");
        var cat = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Processor Information");
        var instances = cat.GetInstanceNames();
        var cs = new Dictionary<string, CounterSample>();

        foreach (var s in instances)
        {
            pc.InstanceName = s;
            cs.Add(s, pc.NextSample());
        }

        while (true)
        {
            foreach (var s in instances)
            {
                pc.InstanceName = s;
                coresUCCurListBox.Items.Add(Calculate(cs[s], pc.NextSample()).ToString());
                cs[s] = pc.NextSample();
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
```

I prefer not to use Performance counters or WMI because they take 6.5 seconds to process. I want to monitor CPU Usage each second.
and another thing is that this code runs with the UI thread and my Form freezes while running.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: This is two questions. Question (1) measure CPU stats without using WMI (2) How do I prevent blocking calls from freezing the UI. They are unrelated and should be asked as separate questions. Please edit your question so that it relates entirely to the title.

Comment: Actually, let's just assume this is a question about measuring CPU without WMI. Now it's a dupe.